# Lucene IndexReader commit not working

Tags: java, lucene

I have a method that searches and delete documents from my Lucene index.

However, when I run the code twice, it still finds the documents that where marked to be deleted from the previous iteration, and indexReader.hasDeletions() evaluates true.

```
public void duplicatesRemover(String currentIndex) throws Exception {

Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(currentIndex));
IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory, false);
IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

int dups = 0;    
for (int i = 0; i < indexReader.numDocs(); i++) {
  Document doc = indexReader.document(i);
  int articleId = Integer.parseInt(doc.get("articleId"));
  Query q = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("articleId", articleId,  articleId, true, true);
  TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(q, 10);
  if (topDocs.totalHits > 1 ) {
    indexReader.deleteDocument(i);


    System.out.print("Total matches from search found: " + topDocs.totalHits + " articleId = " + articleId);
    System.out.println(" total dups found " + ++dups + "/" + i);

  }
}
if(indexReader.hasDeletions()){
  System.out.println("Has deletions");      
  Map<String, String> commitUserData = new HashMap<String, String>();
  commitUserData.put("foo", "fighter");    
  indexReader.commit(commitUserData);
}

indexSearcher.close();    
indexReader.close();

directory.close();
}
```

Many thanks yogi

Comment: Use most popular tags to describe technology/language you are using. This will help people to find your question and answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Lucene version are you using? The `deleteDocument` and `commit` methods are deprecated. Those actions should be done threw an `IndexWriter` as mentioned [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#deleteDocument%28int%29).

Regarding your problem i don't think it is good practice to manipulate the index while an `IndexSearcher` is open. I would start by checking this direction.

Comment: Thank you for the response dolbi, I was using Lucene 4.0